# jQuery map() table with input fields

Tags: jquery

I have a table where the first two cells are inputfields, and I'm trying to map all of the table data inside an array.  But I don't know how to get the data from the input fields right know it only maps the the other data.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bo7bjxrn/)

```
    <table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Amount</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Price</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Articleid</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Descr</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="amount" type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input class="purchprice" type="text" value="2.00"></td>
      <td>210003</td>
      <td>Example_1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="amount" type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input class="purchprice" type="text" value="19.25"></td>
      <td>128025</td>
      <td>Example_2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="amount" type="text" value="3"></td>
      <td><input class="purchprice" type="text" value="23.45"></td>
      <td>124005</td>
      <td>Example_3</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
<button type="button" class="map">Map table</button>

$('.map').on('click', function() {

  var tableData = $('table tbody td').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();

  console.log($.trim(tableData[0]));
  console.log($.trim(tableData[1]));
  console.log($.trim(tableData[2]));
  console.log($.trim(tableData[3]));

});
```

Comment: `return $(this).is(':has(:input)')?$(':input',this).val():$(this).text();`

Answer (score 1):

Check `td` contains input field in **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and return value based on it.

```
var tableData = $('table tbody td').map(function() {
  return $(this).is(':has(:input)') ? // check td contains input 
    $(':input', this).val() : // if contains return it's value
    $(this).text(); // else return text content
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for `input` in `td` like following.

```
$('.map').on('click', function () {
    var tableData = $('table tbody td').map(function () {
        var input = $('input', this);
        return input.length > 0 ? input.val() : $(this).text();
    }).get();

    console.log($.trim(tableData[0]));
    console.log($.trim(tableData[1]));
    console.log($.trim(tableData[2]));
    console.log($.trim(tableData[3]));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the the tag name inside of `.map`

```
$('.map').on('click', function() {

  //combine input elements and tds with no inputs
  var tableData = $('table tbody td:not(:has(input)),table tbody td input').map(function() {
    //check the tagName and perform relevant action.
    return this.tagName == "INPUT" ? this.value : this.textContent;
  }).get();

  console.log($.trim(tableData[0]));
  console.log($.trim(tableData[1]));
  console.log($.trim(tableData[2]));
  console.log($.trim(tableData[3]));
});
```